# Select an item in one list and link it to an item in another list

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to have two listviews/widgets, side by side. The user would select one item in one list, select an item on the other list, and then click a button to 'map' these items together. The behavior would be to highlight the linked items in each list.

I've been conflicted on how to do this. Each list item would need to store an integer index (the "mapped" item in the other list). I thought at first a QListWidget would do the job, but apparently you cannot subclass QListItemWidget. I'd need to add a single variable, mapped_to, to the subclass.

Would a ListView be better for this purpose? Am I going about this all wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide a [MRE], It seems to me that a QListWidget is enough.

Comment: There was another comment here earlier suggesting that I track this info in a dict instead of in the item. Not sure if that comment was deleted, but it pointed out that I was overthinking the problem. I'm thinking that when the Map button is clicked I get the selected item from each list and store the index of each item together. Way simpler than what I was originally trying to do, you are correct that QListWidget is enough. Giving you the answer thingy since the other comment is gone.